# Parsing Unicode text with TJSONObject returns '????'

Tags: json, delphi, c++builder

I try to use `TJSONObject` classes with Unicode characters but after parsing, I get `????` instead of the original text.

The simple problem is:

```
UnicodeString doc = L"{\"alias\":\"Test ЮРИСЛАВ\"}";
ShowMessage(doc);
TJSONObject* jo=new TJSONObject();
jo->Parse(BytesOf(doc), 0);
ShowMessage(jo->ToString());
```

The first `ShowMessage` shows  correctly text: `ЮРИСЛАВ` 
but after parsing the second `ShowMessage` shows `????` instead of `ЮРИСЛАВ`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `String` insted of `UnicodeString ` for `doc` variable or use `UTF8Encode()` function

Comment: I did it, but same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to something like this:

```
jo = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::UTF8::GetBytes(doc), 0);
```

You should convert your Unicode text into UTF8 before parsing it.

Comment: You can pass the `doc` string directly to `ParseJSONValue()`, you don't need to convert it to a UTF-8 byte array first.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `BytesOf()`, which converts a `UnicodeString` to a byte array using the OS default Ansi encoding.  `TJSONObject::Parse()` *prefers* UTF-8 instead.  It looks for a UTF-8 BOM and if not found then it makes no assumptions about the encoding of the bytes, it just treats them as 8-bit characters.  That will not work when dealing with non-ASCII characters, you need to use UTF-8 instead.  To convert a `UnicodeString` to a UTF-8 encoded byte array, you can use `TEncoding::UTF8::GetBytes()`, but you would have to prepend the array with a UTF-8 BOM manually:

```cpp
UnicodeString doc = L"{\"alias\":\"Test ЮРИСЛАВ\"}";
ShowMessage(doc);

TBytes bytes;
bytes.Length = 3 + TEncoding::UTF8::GetByteCount(doc);
bytes[0] = 0xEF;
bytes[1] = 0xBB;
bytes[2] = 0xBF;
TEncoding::UTF8::GetBytes(doc, 1, doc.Length(), bytes, 3);

TJSONObject* jo = new TJSONObject();
jo->Parse(bytes, 0);
ShowMessage(jo->ToString());
//...
delete jo;
```

That being said, you should be using the static `TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue()` method instead of `TJSONValue::Parse()` directly.  `ParseJSONValue()` even has an overload that accepts a `UnicodeString` as input and will convert it to a  UTF-8 encoded byte array internally for you:

```cpp
UnicodeString doc = L"{\"alias\":\"Test ЮРИСЛАВ\"}";
ShowMessage(doc);
TJSONObject* jo = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(doc);
ShowMessage(jo->ToString());
//...
delete jo;
```

But, if you did need to pass in your own byte array, the other overloads of `ParseJSONValue()` allow you to specify whether the byte array is UTF-8 encoded or not (it assumes UTF-8 by default) so you don't need a BOM:

```cpp
UnicodeString doc = L"{\"alias\":\"Test ЮРИСЛАВ\"}";
ShowMessage(doc);
TJSONObject* jo = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::UTF8::GetBytes(doc), 0, true);
ShowMessage(jo->ToString());
//...
delete jo;
```